# Creating THREE js extrudeGeometry from svg path

Tags: svg, three.js

I'm trying to generate a 3d map of the boroughs of London using Three js. I've reverse engineered this example: http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_extrude_shapes2.html 
using this svg file: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/29/London-boroughs.svg

So, I'm passing svg path strings such as:

```
M130.833,250.833L135.5,262.5l14,42.667l-6.333,4l-4.667,3.667l1,3.666l-14.333,3  c0,0,0.333,3.334,4.667,5.667s16,2.667,17,3.667s0.667,6.333,0.667,6.333l-5.667,6.333l-0.667,6.667l-1.667,2l-3.333,1.333l-4.667,6  l-1.333,10l-2.667,8l-4-0.333c0,0,0.667,6.001-0.333,9.667s-2,9.666-5,11.333S112.5,396,112.5,396"
```

into the transformSVGPath function, and it kind of works except the vertices seem to be interpolated badly.

I get the console error "three.js:34023 THREE.ShapeUtils: Unable to triangulate polygon! in triangulate()" and it looks like this:

[image: what it looks like]

Comment: Do you have a live example?

Answer (score 0):

On examination of the SVG, it is a collection of lines over a primary closed shape. The primary shape is the first element in the SVG file and encompasses all of London. The rest of the paths are simply lineTo and bezier curves which define the borders. This is done so that the svg file size will be efficient and that shared edges of boroughs are not doubled - a classic 2d mapping issue. 3d is a different problem space - extrude path in Three.js requires discrete outline shapes to form a complete closed shape. This SVG file is unusable for 3d or polygons. You're better off finding each borough as a single SVG/polygon and importing them each individually if you can find them.

I believe you will find this file more usable as each borough is a discrete shape, but it will still need tayloring to remove the strokes: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:London_boroughs.svg